# Binary addition operation in array consisting of 0's and 1's only

Tags: python

I have the following array:

```
binary_array = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

What I want to do is that I want to start a for loop and change the elements of the array as though I am performing a binary addition operation. For instance,

- In the 1st step, the array will become `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`,
- In the 2nd step, the array will become `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]`,
- In the 3rd step, the array will become `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]`, etc.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each iteration, you may add to try a `1` frmo the right

- if you see a `0`, change to a `1` and stop
- if you see a `1`, change to a `0` and move to one index to the left

```
values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in range(10):

    for idx in range(len(values) - 1, -1, -1):
        if values[idx] == 0:
            values[idx] = 1
            break
        elif values[idx] == 1:
            values[idx] = 0

    print(values)
```

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```